# extra backward slash along with quotes on jsonencode a json array object

Tags: json, terraform, hcl

In terraform,I am trying to make a PUT call via curl command using null_resource and executing the command in local_exec provisioner. The body of the request is json array.

The command expects the data to be in string format. I have the data as tuple in locals. I am using *jsonencode* to serialize the tupple to a string and pass to curl. But on jsonencode, the string formed has an additional \ prefixed before each " in json string.

eg. expected json string is:

```
"[{"key-1" : "value-1", "key-2": "value-2"}]"
```

But after jsonencode, the formatted string is as follows:

```
"[{\"key-1\" : \"value-1\", \"key-2\": \"value-2\"}]"
```

additional backslash is added along with quotes.

Because of the malformed request body, the API returns Bad Request response.

How can we correctly serialize the tupple/list to correct json string in Terraform and pass to curl command?

This is my null_resource:

```
resource "null_resource" "call_API" {
  for_each = { for x in local.array: x.name => {
    name = x.name
    vars = jsonencode(x.vars)
  } }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
        curl -X PUT ${var.url} -d ${each.value.vars}  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Authorization:${local.bearer_token}'
        EOF
  }
```

Comment: What is the local variable `array`? Can you add  that as well?

Comment: Also, the leading and closing quotes do not create a valid JSON array. If you remove those, it is recognized as JSON.

Comment: local variable array is an input which again a json array of another structure, which contains vars inside. Updated the question to give an idea of the input.

Comment: Wait, so the local variable is already JSON formatted?

Comment: yes, need to convert to string as curl shows error as it expects string format. So using jsonencode and getting the additional characters.

Comment: Well, then you need `jsondecode`?

Comment: No, as I already mentioned in the description, the command expects data in string format. If jsondecode would have solved, then there was no need of jsonencode in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that the JSON is the cause of the error. The `curl` command line is the most probable cause of the error. It is, most probably, executed using a shell and the JSON contains a lot of characters that are special to the shell. The argument of `-d` must be enclosed in apostrophes, to make sure that the shell does not split it into words or tries to interpret it and passes it as a single argument to `curl`. It should be `-d '${each.value.vars}'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand that you want to pass this variable

```
"[{"key-1" : "value-1", "key-2": "value-2"}]"
```

You tried to use `EOF`?
You can do something like that

```
variable "body" {
  type = "string"
}

variable = <<EOF
"[{"key-1" : "value-1", "key-2": "value-2"}]"
EOF
```

Or with `EOT`, honestly I don't remember which one work

EDIT:
If the json is not static and you receive it from other module or others, you can try to expand the variable inside the EOFs

```
body = <<EOF
${var.json}
EOF
```

Comment: No, this json is not created locally, it is passed as a variable.

Comment: @Dipumon check if the EDIT part can be a possible solution for you